# Couldn't make connection to a target machine through TCP Client C#

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my code below. I just try to connect to a target IP but it always throw an exception "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

The target client machine is not online so it can't accept or deny the connection from the Server side. On the server, I want it keep trying to connect to the client til connected. Somehow it doesn't work as expected.

I thought the reason was antivirus or firewall so I did disable those but the issue is still. Is there anyone can test the code and let me know why it always throw that exception?

Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        public static TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        public static int port = 6446;
        public static string connectTo = "192.168.0.11";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connecting...");
                    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(connectTo);
                    client.Connect(ipAddress, port);

                } while (client.Connected != true);
                //dataStream = client.GetStream();
                //getMessages.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());  }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an internal IP, only you or other people on they network segment can reach it. You could always try ping or telnet to a specific port. Telnet will connect, timeout or say connection refused.